# Removing indentation introduced by an environment

Tags: environments

The following environment is introducing indentations, and I want to avoid it.  Using `{%` and `}%` did not help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{wvPzz}{O{orange}mmo}
     {%
       \smallskip%
       \IfNoValueTF {#4}
           {%
              #2 \ #3 \hspace{\parindent}%
           }%
         {%
            #2 \ #3 \ (#4)%
            \smallskip \par%
         }%
       \color{#1}%
    }%
  {%
     \smallskip%
  }

Some Text Here

\begin{wvPzz}{aa}{bb}
  Some Text
\end{wvPzz}

Write Something

\begin{wvPzz}{aa}{bb}[cc]
  Some Text
\end{wvPzz}

Write Something

\begin{wvPzz}[blue]{aa}{bb}
  Some Text
\end{wvPzz}

A prime number is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If I make your code compilable by loading the `color` or `xcolor` package, every single line that's generated is indented. *Which* line, or lines, should *not* be indented? All of them? Some of them? If so, which ones?

Comment: `aa` and `Some Text` when written on the next line should not be indented.

Comment: @Barytoc `aa` isn't indented. It isn't at the beginning of a line. There's a space between `Some text` and `aa` but that looks just like the other interword spaces .... Also your final `\smallskip` is ignored. You can't leave a blank line before the argument specifying code to be executed at the end of an environment.

Comment: The same at the start. If you compile the code you pasted, you'll find no colour used at all. So it is clear neither part of the definition is actually ever used.

Comment: Have added a paragraph at the end where there is an indentation at the start.  I can see the colours.

Comment: @cfr I want some spacing  after the end of the environment and the any paragraph following it.  Your wording is too difficult for me to understand.

Comment: I have added `Some Text Here` at the start.  The text of the environments do not align with `Some Text Here`, but have been shifted towards the right.

Comment: If I copy-paste your code and compile it, I do not get colours. I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Lhz.png. You need to check that the code you post gives the output you expect or we're just talking about different things.

Comment: Have found that the problem happened because I had blank lines in the definition of the new environment.

Comment: Now you can see that `divisors` is not aligned with `aa`.

Comment: the indentation is unrelated to the environment definition, it's simply the normal indentation at the start of a paragraph

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear which indentations you want to suppress, as there are none added by the environment definition, just normal paragraph indnentation.
Note however you should add vertical skips in vertical mode so precede by `\par` or a blank line.  I added `\noindent` so (as you asked in a comment, not in the question) `aa` aligns with`divisors`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{wvPzz}{O{orange}mmo}
     {% par before smallskip
       \smallskip%
       \IfNoValueTF {#4}
           {%
% this is very weird, after #3, you get a word space, parindent???
% and thenpossibly a word space or paragraph break or possibly no space
% then the text from the body of the environment.
            \noindent  #2 \ #3 \hspace{\parindent}% 
           }%
         {%
% as above the behaviour after (#4) is somewhat variable
            #2 \ #3 \ (#4)%
% \par before \smallskip, not after
            \par\smallskip
         }%
       \color{#1}%
    }%
  {%
    % par (or blank line) before smallskip
    \par
     \smallskip%
  }

Some Text Here

\begin{wvPzz}{aa}{bb}
  Some Text
\end{wvPzz}

Write Something

\begin{wvPzz}{aa}{bb}[cc]
  Some Text
\end{wvPzz}

Write Something

\begin{wvPzz}[blue]{aa}{bb}
  Some Text
\end{wvPzz}

A prime number is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive
divisors other than 1 and itself.

\end{document}
```